# Why is there a large space between center (10 column) section and right (1 column) section of a page made with Foundation (Zurb)?

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

Tried to find this in another question.. to no avail.  Some were close, but not exact.  So here goes..

So here's the code:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-1 columns left_border">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="small-10 columns">
            <p>Silva salvus animalis est Silva salvus animalis est Silva salvus animalis est Silva salvus animalis est Silva salvus animalis est Silva salvus animalis est Silva salvus animalis est Silva salvus animalis est Silva salvus animalis est </p>
        </div>
        <div class="small-1 columns right_border">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is what it renders:

[image]

What's with this space in the middle set of columns?

Other than the base foundation css, here's the only modifiers I've added to the app.css file:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #17233F;
    background-image: url(../images/tall_body.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.columns {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.left_border {
    background-image: url('../images/bg_lt.gif');
    width: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 284px;
}

.right_border {
    background-image: url('../images/bg_rt.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 284px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post related CSS for all?

Comment: Just realized I didn't..  added.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happen because in Grid Design you shouldn't add Fix with to your grids.
In this code remove `width: 20px;` from `.left_border` and `.right_border` to solved your problem.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  That did the trick.  Thanks Parhum.